# No module named 'django' - uWSGI and python venv issue

Tags: python, django, uwsgi, python-venv

I tried to use uWSGI with my django application for testing, but I got the error.

*Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./sitefirst/wsgi.py", line 12, in 
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
ImportError: No module named 'django*

It seems uWSGi is not activating my Python venv, **fisrtsite**. I use the following command.

`uwsgi --http :8080 -H /home/mo/firstsite --chdir /home/mo/sitefirst -w sitefirst.wsgi`

My venv **fisrtsite** has python 3.7 and has Django. uWSGi comes with Python 3.5.2 and this version does not have have Django.

I created venv called **fisrtsite** and install Django and created test Django project. I installed uWSGI globally to create less friction in handling multiple Django projects.

`sudo apt-get install python3-dev`

`sudo -H pip3 install uwsgi`

I am sure that uwsgi installed successfully. I tested using a simple python file and it works.

My linux server is Ubuntu with python 2 as default.

Any help and thought would be appreciated.

Comment: How did you created your `venv`?

Comment: Please show the file structire of `/home/mo/sitefirst`

Comment: I created venv using ```Python3.7 -m venv fisrtsite```